# How to enter transactions in a drupal environment

Tags: views

I use drupal extensively, but I notice that one cannot enter data as if in the following situation: Suppose that you have a master  file containing (Customer name,  DOB, Date of first visit...etc ) and other fixed information. And suppose one will need to record the amount in Dollars of different purchases made on several visit for a customer. In this case there will be several purchases amount that must be recorded on different possible visits for that customer. How one can record these transactions in drupal and how one can display the sum of these amounts in a view for that customer.  I have reviewed view group module, but the important thing here is how one can enter the data before thinking to do any calculation. I would appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: Why isn't a multi-valued field enough?

Comment: Have you tried accomplishing it with node references?